# How to add a flag-icon in angular select dropdown

Tags: angular

In the below code the flag is not displaying inside the select, if using it outside select the flag is displaying
Package used: flag-icons

```
HTML
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.code">
      <span class="fi fi-us"></span>
      {{ country.name }}
    </option>
  </select>

TS
  selectedCountry: string;
  countries = [
    { name: 'United States', code: 'US' },
    { name: 'Canada', code: 'CA' },
    { name: 'United Kingdom', code: 'GB' },
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to the usage of the flag icon class (fi) within the span tag inside the option element. The select element may not render HTML content inside its option elements consistently across browsers.
To display the flag inside the select element, you can try using a library like ngx-flag-icon or similar that provides a custom component for displaying flag icons.

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.code">
         <ngx-flag-icon [country]="country.code" size="md"></ngx-flag-icon>
         {{ country.name }}
      </option>
    </select>`
```